# Formatting multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here I have a multidimensional array storing information about certain states. All of the information displays but I'm having troubles formatting it into a 4x11 table.

```
<?php

$stateinfo = array
(
        array("Alabama","Montgomery","4,779,736",23),
        array("Alaska", "Juneau", "710,231", 47),
        array("Arizona","Phoenix","6,329,017", 18),
        array("Arkansas","Little Rock", "2,915,918", 32),
        array("California","Sacramento","37,253,956",1),
        array("Colorado","Denver","5,029,196",22),
        array("Connecticut","Hartford","3,518,288",29),
        array("Delaware","Dover","897,934",45),
        array("Florida","Tallahassee","18,801,310",4),
        array("Georgia","Atlanta","9,687,653",9),
        array("Hawaii","Honolulu","1,360,301",42)
);

 for($row = 0; $row <count($stateinfo);$row++)
 {
        for($col=0;$col <count($stateinfo[$row]);$col++)
        {
                echo $stateinfo[$row][$col];
        }
         echo "<br>";
 }
 ?>
```

current output:

[image]

needed output:

[image]

Comment: Why would you expect your output to be anything different?

Comment: There are many ways to approach this. The answers here are technically correct, but perhaps not to the author's taste preferences? It should be easy enough simply to modify the part where you echo each value and add some styling ... you can use divs, css, tables, &tab; etc.

Comment: Did you give up or what?

Answer (score -1):

I would just do this:

```
<table>
<?php
foreach($stateinfo as $row) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>', $row).'</td></tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

Then apply styles to the table/td to get specific spacing.

Answer (score -2):

It seems like you just want some formatting? Then when you loop to print your multidimensional array, just add a few `&nbsp;` between each element or `padding:5px;` to it. There are literally a million ways to accomplish this:

- Display through default HTML table
- Using no-breakline spaces
- Wrap in `span` with padding or margin
  ...